# Updating javascript string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I got an URL containing a bunch of parameters, hereunder the following as well;

```
conditions=[{"name”:”foo”,”operator”:”bar”,”value":350000}]
```

This can also be the folowing

```
conditions=[]
```

and

```
conditions=[{"name”:”one”,”operator”:”two”,”value":350000}, {"name”:”three”,”operator”:”one”,”value”:22}]
```

It could theoretically also be

```
conditions=[{"name”:”one”,”operator”:”two”,”value":350000}, {"name”:”three”,”operator”:”one”,”value”:22}, {"name”:”four”,”operator”:”two”,”value”:22}, {"name”:”sixty”,”operator”:”three”,”value”:22}, ..]
```

Based on an input I want to change the conditions=[]. I got the following variables in my code

```
inputName, obj, valueOperator
```

These could contain the following values:

```
inputName = “three”
valueOperator = “two”
obj.value = 22
```

So from this i can construct the conditions as describer earlier. Now to my issue;

I want to break up the `conditions=[]` and check if there is anything in the brackets, if not, I’ll just add my new condition. If there is something, I want to check if the `inputName` matches any **“name”** in bracket. If not, I’ll just add my new condition. If it matches I want to update the value and operator with my new variables. When I’m done I want to put back together the `conditions=[]`. With the updated conditions. It will always only update one condition at a time.

I'm pretty much lost. Does anybody have a great idea?

Comment: `conditions=[{"name”:”foo”,”operator”:”bar”,”value":350000}]` (and the same in many of the other snippets) is invalid syntax - curly quotes often break things in programming, best to avoid them

Comment: CertainPerformance, damn.. Unfortunately I can't change it, I'm working with a partner service which provides me the link. I'm just trying to manipulate the content based on the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the explanation you have provided, i tried to replicate it. Hope this works.

```
const inputName = 'three';
const valueOperator = 'two';
const obj = 22;

let conditions = [
  { name: 'one', operator: 'two', value: 350000 },
  { name: 'two', operator: 'one', value: 22 }
];

if (conditions.length == 0) {
  conditions.push({ name: inputName, operator: valueOperator, value: obj });
} else {
  let found = false;
  for (const condition of conditions) {
    if (condition.name == inputName) {
      condition.operator = valueOperator;
      condition.value = obj;
      found = true; // mark found as true when name found
    }
  }

  // Insert values if not found in conditions
  if (!found) {
    conditions.push({ name: inputName, operator: valueOperator, value: obj });
  }
}

console.log(conditions);
```

Comment: This led me directly to my solution! Thank you Pawan! Keep up the good work

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following `url`:

```
https://example.com/myfolder/?conditions=[{"name”:”foo”,”operator”:”bar”,”value":350000}]
```

then the value of the `queryString` parameter `conditions` is a JSON string.

To turn that value into a `javascript object`, you need the following:

```
// CAPTURE THE QUERY STRING IN A URLSearchParams OBJECT INSTANCE
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// GET THE RELEVANT JSON STRING FROM urlParams
let conditionsJSON = urlParams.get('conditions');

// CONVERT THE JSON STRING INTO A JAVASCRIPT OBJECT
let conditionsObject = JSON.parse(conditionsJSON);
```

You will now have an `array` (`conditionsObject`) which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name : "foo",
    operator : "bar",
    value : 350000
  }
]
```

---

**N.B.** To avoid confusion, in javascript, an `array` is a *specific kind* of `object` - so the code above represents both an `array` ***and*** an `object` (because the former represents a subset of the latter).

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
const inputName = 'foo'
const valueOperator = 'two'
const value = 22

const conditionString = 'condition=[{"name”:”foo”,”operator”:”bar”,”value":350000}]'
const data = JSON.parse(conditionString.substr(10).replace(/”/g, '"'))

const newData = { name: inputName, operator: valueOperator, value: value }
let ind = data.findIndex(v => v.name === inputName) 
if (ind < 0) ind = data.length

data[ind] = newData
const newConditionsString = `conditions=${JSON.stringify(data)}`
console.log(newConditionsString)
```

Answer (score 0):

First part of your problem can be taken care by the solution provided by Rounin. For the second part where you want to work on condition matching based on name, below code should be able to help you.

```
inputName="Three"
valueOperator = "two"
value = 22

if(conditionsObject.length!=0){
    let index = conditionsObject.findIndex((item)=>item.name==inputName)
    if(index!=-1){
        conditionsObject[index].value = value
        conditionsObject[index].operator = valueOperator
    }
    else{
    conditionsObject.push({ name: inputName, operator: valueOperator, value: value })
    }
else{
    conditionsObject.push({ name: inputName, operator: valueOperator, value: value })
}
}
```